# Centering full-page Tikz image on page without margins with xelatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, positioning

I'm trying to export some full-page SVG images via `inkscape2tikz`, and then trying to include these tikz-code images in a Latex document; but there seems to be a slight problem with `xelatex`.

After checking

- [How does TiKZ calculate positioning of picture on page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-does-tikz-calculate-positioning-of-picture-on-page/1788#1788)
- [How to include PDF absolute positioned and scaled?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46658/how-to-include-pdf-absolute-positioned-and-scaled)

... I came up with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{cff0000}{RGB}{255,0,0}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

\node at (current page.north west) {%

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west]

    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.34461553)}]% layer1

      % rect3016
      \path[color=black,fill=cff0000,line width=0.800pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm]
        (0.0000,-0.3446) rectangle (524.4094,743.7499);

    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}

};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, if I build this with `pdflatex`:

- after first build, the rectangle is positioned wrong - but
- after second build, the rectangle is correctly positioned

But, if I build with `xelatex`:

- after first build, the rectangle is positioned way out
- after second build, the rectangle is positioned differently, but still wrong.

Here is what `xelatex` produces after multiple runs (kinda hard to see here, but download the image to see the positioning of the red rectangle vs. the white background):

[image: xelatex rectangle fail]

Obviously, I'd like to have the red rectangle centered on page (or aligned at top left corner, doesn't matter) - so that the red rectangle takes up most of the page.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: @sdaay Just `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: Thanks for that, @YiannisLazarides - `hyperref` works great as well! Cheers!

Comment: Another option would be to use `\documentclass[tikz=true]{standalone}` to create a pdf from your svg and then include the pdf with `\includegraphics{}` in your article

Comment: Thanks for that, @matth - that sounds good; however, I wanted to avoid also having .pdf in addition to the tikz code (and having to then scale and align the .pdf's to entire page).. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` to your preamble: this will pass the drivers the correct page size.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @egreg - works great! Cheers!