# unexpected vertical gaps when using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

in the following minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary {calc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\parindent=0mm

\begin{document}

\eject
\pdfpagewidth=320mm
\pdfpageheight=220mm

% page#cover
\setcounter{page}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0] at (10mm, -10mm) {
      \includegraphics[width=300mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
    };
    \draw[anchor=north west, black]
      (10mm, 0mm) --
      (10mm, -10mm) --
      (0mm, -10mm);
    \draw[anchor=north west, black]
      (310mm, -220mm) --
      (310mm, -210mm) --
      (320mm, -210mm);

  \fontsize{64}{76}\selectfont
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at (155mm, -20mm) {
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000
    \begin{minipage}{160mm}
      \rightskip=0pt plus .2\hsize
      \centering
      \textcolor{blue}{
        Title title
      }
    \end{minipage}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\eject
\pdfpagewidth=440mm
\pdfpageheight=220mm

% page#1
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0] at (10mm, -10mm) {
      \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
    };
    \draw[anchor=north west, black]
      (10mm, 0mm) --
      (10mm, -10mm) --
      (0mm, -10mm);
    \draw[anchor=north west, black]
      (210mm, -220mm) --
      (210mm, -210mm) --
      (220mm, -210mm);

  \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at (30mm, -30mm) {
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \rightskip=0pt plus .2\hsize
      \textcolor{red}{
        some example text
      }
    \end{minipage}
  };

  \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at (15mm, -195mm) {
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \rightskip=0pt plus .2\hsize
      3
    \end{minipage}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

% page#2
\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0] at (230mm, -10mm) {
      \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}
    };
    \draw[black]
      (230mm, 0mm) --
      (230mm, -10mm) --
      (220mm, -10mm);
    \draw[black]
      (430mm, -220mm) --
      (430mm, -210mm) --
      (440mm, -210mm);

  \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at (230mm, -30mm) {
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000
    \begin{minipage}{160mm}
      \rightskip=0pt plus .2\hsize
      \textcolor{purple}{
        some example text
      }
    \end{minipage}
  };

  \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at (420mm, -195mm) {
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \rightskip=0pt plus .2\hsize
      4
    \end{minipage}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

it renders the following:

[image]

and

[image]

... in the 1st PDF page, the whole thing is shifted down by a few mm

... and in the 2nd PDF page, the left `tikzimage` is shifted down by a few mm again, and then the right `tikzimage` is shifted down by a further few mm.

worth noting that these gaps are vertical-only, whatever is causing these gaps do not appear to have any horizontal effect.

what is causing these unexpected "gaps"?
how to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55420/231952, «what `TikZ` needs is to know the paper dimensions and apparently it uses `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`». So you need to set also `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.
I can not explain why `TikZ` create those gaps but you can remove them by using the `current page` nodes. In such a case you can do without `geometry` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[margin=0mm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\eject
\pdfpagewidth=320mm
\pdfpageheight=220mm
\paperwidth=320mm
\paperheight=220mm

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0,xshift=10mm,yshift=-10mm] at (current page.north west) {%
  \includegraphics[width=300mm, height=200mm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\eject
\pdfpagewidth=440mm
\pdfpageheight=220mm
\paperwidth=440mm
\paperheight=220mm

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0,xshift=10mm,yshift=-10mm] at (current page.north west) {
  \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
 \draw node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0,xshift=-10mm,yshift=-10mm] at (current page.north east) {%
  \includegraphics[width=200mm, height=200mm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm.. ok that appears to have worked for my images, but I got stuck trying to apply the same pattern to my lines, e.g.
````
\draw[black, anchor=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (current page.north west)
      (230mm, 0mm) --
      (230mm, -10mm) --
      (220mm, -10mm);
```
yields
```
! Use of \@next doesn't match its definition.
l.117 ...=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at
                                                   (current page.north west)
```

Comment: is there a way to use a `at (current page.north west)` on a regular `draw` command without a `node`?

Comment: figured out how to do ^ using `/node` --> `/tikz` --> `/draw`