# How to make an environment for a tikz nodes content

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, environments

(Sorry the title is not very good.)

I came across [Centering full-page tikz images - with mid-document paper size change](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/centering-full-page-tikz-images-with-mid-document-paper-size-change/55421#comment1604064_55421) and its answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55421/11820 which I use as a wrapper for fullpage tikz pictures. Now I want to put it into an environment, but this does not work for

```
\node at (current page.north west) { … }
```

as `\node at (current page.north west) {` would be at the beginning of the environment and the closing brace `}` at the end.

How can I "embrace" the whole environment content?

MWE (not working)

```
\newenvironment{tikzpicturebase}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.north west) {%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,yscale=-1]
}
{
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Please post *full* compilable code aka a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317), thanks. Note: nested `tikzpicture` environments aren't supported, AFAIK. This is likely to break.

Comment: Looks like the same question as [Defining a new environment whose contents go in a TikZ node - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5639/defining-a-new-environment-whose-contents-go-in-a-tikz-node)

Answer (score 2):

Nested `tikzpictures` are unsupported and unneeded here, as far as I understand the goal. You can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to avoid the brace-balancing issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{foobar}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
          fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] at (current page.north west)
      \bgroup\ignorespaces
  }%
  {%
      \unskip\egroup;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{foobar}
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This technique is robust in that you can even use verbatim material (or other nasty beasts that change category codes) in the environment body. For instance:

```
\begin{foobar}
  \Huge \verb|@#{}!%|
\end{foobar}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `environ` package has a `\BODY` macro that contains what you have fed to the environment. If I have understood your wishes correctly I think that this could work for you. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{tikzpicturebase}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node at (current page.north west) {\BODY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicturebase}
        Hello! I am in the upper left corner! :)
    \end{tikzpicturebase}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not nest `tikzpicture`s — dragons will be there. But if you have a new enough latex, you can "grab" the whole environment using the `+b` type of parameter, and you can nest a `tikzpicture` using a box to save it.

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{north west} +b}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=#1] at (current page.#1) {#2};
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newbox{\abox}
\sbox{\abox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[red, ultra thick](0,0) circle[radius=20pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}[center]
    \usebox{\abox}
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the snippet above]

Comment: `\begin{foo} \verb|@#{}!%| \end{foo}` makes TeX rather unhappy! :-) (ditto for the `environ`-based solution)

Comment: @frougon you're right, but in my defense the OP didn't ask for nasty catcode-changing content.... ;-)

Comment: True, I was “just pointing out” 'cause I felt in minority against *two* argument-grabbing techniques. :)