# Problem with setting correct custom page size with 'geometry' in xelatex

Tags: xetex, paper-size, geometry

I'm trying to set the page size using the `geometry` package as shown in the following MWE, compiled with `xelatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[b5paper,pass]{geometry}
\geometry{b5paper}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}

\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\drawpage}{\ifdrawparameters}{\iftrue}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage fixed*******^^J}}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage not fixed*******^^J}}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If I then try to check the page size using `pdfinfo` (on Ubuntu), I get size of US letter (?!):

```
$ pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 1 test.pdf | grep Page
Pages:          1
Page    1 size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
```

However, if I enter `b5paper` in `\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}` - then I can just as well delete all the other references to `geometry` using `b5paper` - because when I compile with that change, I get:

```
$ pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 1 test.pdf | grep Page
Pages:          1
Page    1 size: 498.9 x 708.66 pts
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   498.90   708.66
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   498.90   708.66
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   498.90   708.66
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   498.90   708.66
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   498.90   708.66
```

... which (I guess) corresponds to correct B5 measures.

Now, as far as I had believed until now - one should be able to change the paper size with `geometry` - as long as those changes are issued before `\begin{document}`, is that correct? If so, why doesn't it work here?

I'm wandering, because I wanted to set some custom page sizes with `geometry` in this way (and which thus I couldn't propagate to the `\documentclass` command).

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to set a custom page size in this example,
Cheers!

Comment: You have to pass `b5paper` as an option to `\documentclass` rather than to `geometry`.

Comment: Thanks for that, @egreg - but I wanted a solution outside of `\documentclass`, since I want to set custom page sizes.. I came up with a sort of a hack [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55713/2595), but I'm not sure if that is the way custom page sizes should be handled.. Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, finally I think I got somewhere with switching between custom page sizes and page layouts with `geometry` in mid-document (the MWE is below (<sup>see also [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55713/2595) on `geometry`'s `pass`</sup>); click on image for full size):

[image]

First of all, a couple of words about geometry:

- You can call `\geometry` **only** in preamble, and there multiple commands have simply the effect of replacing previously set values of parameters
- `geometry` first calculates a layout (margins etc) **after** `\begin{document}`, which the manual calls layout L1
- The command `\restoregeometry` can only restore L1!
- The command `\newgeometry` can **only** be called *after* `\begin{document}` (*and thus, after L1 is created*)
- Layouts created with `\newgeometry` can be `\save`/`\loadgeometry`-ied
- `\newgeometry` does **NOT** care about `\paperwidth`/`height`! In fact, if you thought you could cheat with:

  ```
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{100mm}
  \setlength{\paperheight}{100mm}
  \newgeometry{twoside,...}
  ```

  , `geometry` will care *not a bit*, and will in fact reset paperwidth/height back to the documentclass setting (or I guess, the last named page size setting in `geometry`, if any).
- However, `geometry` **does** take into account parameters called `layoutwidth` and `layoutheight`, which serve the purpose of page size limits.

Thus, how `geometry` calculates margins, is independent of the actual page setting in `\paperwidth`/`\pdfpagewidth`. Having all this in mind, the following checklist can be submitted for managing custom page sizes and layouts:

- Prepare in preamble custom page sizes as new lengths
- Prepare in preamble commands `\generatePageLayouts`, `\switchToLayoutPageA` and `\switchToLayoutPageB`
- After `\begin{document}`, call first `\generatePageLayouts`, not doing any actual page size switching with `\paperwidth`/`\pdfpagewidth`

  - it will call `\newgeometry` with `layoutwidth`/`height` set to respective custom pagesize newlengths, and then `\savegeometry`
- Then `\switchToLayoutPageA` and typeset content

  - it will do actual page switching with `\paperwidth`/`\pdfpagewidth`, and call respective `loadgeometry`
- Then `\switchToLayoutPageB` and typeset content

  - it will -- || --

Note that even `\loadgeometry` resets `\paperwidth`/`height` - which can be seen on the image, in the table produced by `layouts`: there it is reported, on *both* pages, that: `\paperwidth = 614.295pt` - even if neither of the pages is of that size:

```
$ pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 2 test.pdf | grep Page
Pages:          2
Page    1 size: 300 x 400 pts
Page    2 size: 400 x 500 pts
```

In any case, here is the MWE, compiled with `xelatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% reminder: US letter: 596pt x 795pt

\newlength{\pagewidthA}
\newlength{\pageheightA}
\setlength{\pagewidthA}{300bp}
\setlength{\pageheightA}{400bp}

\newlength{\pagewidthB}
\newlength{\pageheightB}
\setlength{\pagewidthB}{400bp}
\setlength{\pageheightB}{500bp}

\newlength{\stockwidth}
\newlength{\stockheight}


\usepackage{geometry}

% these seem to have NO effect in preamble!
% geometry first has effect after begin{document}!
\pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthA \pdfpageheight=\pageheightA % to enforce?
\paperwidth=\pagewidthA \paperheight=\pageheightA     % for TikZ
\stockwidth=\pagewidthA \stockheight=\pageheightA % hyperref (memoir)?!

% this command will take effect into L1 layout just after \begin{document}
\geometry{twoside,inner=50bp,outer=30bp,top=50bp,bottom=50bp}


\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\drawpage}{\ifdrawparameters}{\iftrue}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage fixed*******^^J}}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage not fixed*******^^J}}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printpagevalues}{%
  % from geometry.sty:
  * paper: \ifx\Gm@paper\@undefined<default>\else\Gm@paper\fi \\%
  * layout: \ifGm@layout<custom>\else<same size as paper>\fi \\%
  \@ifundefined{ifGm@layout}{}{%
  \ifGm@layout
  * layout(width,height): (\the\Gm@layoutwidth,\the\Gm@layoutheight) \\%
  \fi
  * layoutoffset:(h,v)=(\the\Gm@layouthoffset,\the\Gm@layoutvoffset) \\%
  }%
  \pagevalues % from package layouts
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\generatePageLayouts}{%
  % this command must be called after \begin{document}!

  % geometry needs layoutwidth - cause it ignores the above paper sizes!
  % layoutwidth=148mm ok, layoutwidth=\paperwidth NOT ok
  % paperwidth gets reset again internally in newgeometry: in log: *geometry* verbose mode: * layout(width,height): (614.295pt,794.96999pt)
  % but by using \stockwidth, which here is just a custom length: * layout(width,height): (421.10078pt,597.50787pt)

  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthA,layoutheight=\pageheightA,left=1mm,right=5mm,bottom=1mm,top=1mm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageA}

  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthB,layoutheight=\pageheightB,twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=0.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageB}
}

\newcommand{\switchToLayoutPageA}{%
  % doesn't include page sizes; so page size too:
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthA \pdfpageheight=\pageheightA % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthA \paperheight=\pageheightA     % for TikZ
  \stockwidth=\pagewidthA \stockheight=\pageheightA % hyperref (memoir)?!
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageA} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}

\newcommand{\switchToLayoutPageB}{%
  % doesn't include page sizes; so page size too:
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthB \pdfpageheight=\pageheightB % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthB \paperheight=\pageheightB     % for TikZ
  \stockwidth=\pagewidthB \stockheight=\pageheightB % hyperref (memoir)?!
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageB} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}

\fontspec[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}



\begin{document}
  % here geometry layout L1 is instantiated;
  % without anything else, paper size defaults to US letter!
  % \restoregeometry command restores L1!!

  \fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont % this nowork in preamble!


  % generate page layouts first based on layoutwidth as page size;
  % don't switch actual page sizes yet:
  \generatePageLayouts{}


  %%% start with content

  % start with LayoutPageA (includes switching page size)
  \switchToLayoutPageA{}


    \pagestyle{empty} % no page numbers here
    \\
     \the\paperwidth
    \lipsum[1]
    \printpagevalues{}
    \clearpage

  % switch to LayoutPageB (includes switching page size)
  \switchToLayoutPageB{}


    % start page numbering here ("this will reset the page number"):
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    % make page numbers visible
    \pagestyle{plain}


    \the\paperwidth
    \lipsum[1]

    Trying

    some

    text

    \printpagevalues{}

\end{document}
```

And finally - here is how the above image was generated:

```
convert -density 150 -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 2 test.pdf[0] test1.png
convert -density 150 -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 2 test.pdf[1] test2.png
montage test1.png test2.png -geometry +2+2 -tile 2x1 test.png
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: This was *almost* the solution I needed (really, so close)! I was so happy to achieve the new dimensions. I have exactly the kind of situation where this code would be needed. I have documents sharing a common preamble, but one of the docs is a DVD label with a TikZ drawing. The dimensions are set to fit the DVD tray for printing on DVDs. While the page dimensions change properly, TikZ does not put my absolutely positioned coordinate where I want it :/ (Obviously without some code you probably can't help me-I am aware of that. I just wouldn't even know how to start my question.)

Comment: I opened up a related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230254/how-can-i-readjust-tikzs-dimension-variables-to-fit-mid-document-dimension-chan

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: Ok, I think I finally realized the culprit, which is the `pass` option of the `geometry` package. It turns out, whenever the `pass` option is present in a `geometry` call - regardless if it is in the options of `\usepackage[...]{geometry}`, or if it is a `\geometry{pass}` call right before `\begin{document}` - it will simply "kill" whatever settings for margins you may have set there, and revert to whatever the documentclass was set to, apparently (*so, apparently including the `b5paper` option set below in \usepackage[b5paper,pass]{geometry} was made irrelecant by the subsequent `pass`*).

For instance, I tried setting margins (in code below) with:

```
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=\classpagewidth,paperheight=\classpageheight,twoside,inner=1cm,outer=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
```

... and nothing worked - because `pass` was there!

Knowing that, now I can just replace the `geometry` related commands in the code below with:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{pass,twoside,inner=1cm,outer=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
```

... and all seems to work fine.

Note finally, that while we cannot use `\geometry{pass}` after `\begin{document}` - we can use `\newgeometry{pass}` there; and in that case, `pass` doesn't seem to revert all page lengths so drastically.

(*Btw, using `pass` there was because of a fix to [Centering full-page Tikz image on page without margins with xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55364/2595)*)

---

OK, I think I finally arrived at some sort of a hack/solution/understanding; basically, it seems that settings for the page size in the above example are ignored as part of the `geometry` package, and one has to explicitly set page sizes (as per hack seen in [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document) and elsewhere).

In the example below - note that the explicit setting of page sizes, even if it occurs before `geometry` is loaded, seems to be unaffected by loading of `geometry`'s options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\newlength{\classpageheight}
\newlength{\classpagewidth}
\newlength{\stockwidth}\newlength{\stockheight}

% since here page size stuff may get ignored,
% set explicitly custom page size
\setlength{\classpagewidth}{290pt}
\setlength{\classpageheight}{360pt}
\pdfpagewidth=\classpagewidth \pdfpageheight=\classpageheight % to enforce?
\paperwidth=\classpagewidth \paperheight=\classpageheight     % for TikZ
\stockwidth=\classpagewidth \stockheight=\classpageheight % hyperref (memoir)?!

\usepackage[b5paper,pass]{geometry}
\geometry{b5paper}


\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}

\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\drawpage}{\ifdrawparameters}{\iftrue}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage fixed*******^^J}}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage not fixed*******^^J}}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Note that in the example, I've defined `\stockwidth` only because `layouts` defines it (otherwise for purposes in `memoir`) - which then causes a `hyperref` "*Package hyperref Warning: Height of page (\stockheight) is invalid (0.0pt), ( hyperref) using 11in.*"

If I build this with `xelatex test.tex`, and then check the page size, I get:

```
$ pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 1 test.pdf | grep Page | grep size
Page    1 size: 288.92 x 358.66 pts
```

Notably, I thought I asked for 290 x 360 pts page; but `pdfinfo` says the size is actually 288.92 x 358.66 pts. Turns out, what I need is the 'big points' (bp) [LaTeX length units](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/ltx-86.html) - so if I rewrite:

```
\setlength{\classpagewidth}{290bp}
\setlength{\classpageheight}{360bp}
```

... then indeed `pdfinfo` reports the requested size:

```
$ pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 1 test.pdf | grep Page | grep size
Page    1 size: 290 x 360 pts
```

Still not sure if this is the way things are supposed to be done, though ... Cheers!