# How can I readjust TikZ's dimension variables to fit mid-document dimension change?

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, lengths, dimensions

## Question

How can I readjust TikZ's dimension variables to fit a mid-document dimension change as in this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55852/13552) and using the TikZ drawing from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223851/13552).

## Problem

TikZ coordinates are not where they should be. See [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223851/13552) for the correct coordinate alignment on the page.

### Criteria

Just to clarify:

- Page dimensions must be exactly height=224mm by width=130mm (tray dimensions)
- Origin of disk must be exactly -119.98mm below the top of the page (`current page.north`)

## Procedure

I set my custom lengths for the DVD tray:

```
\newlength{\pagewidthDVDTray}
\newlength{\pageheightDVDTray}
\setlength{\pagewidthDVDTray}{130mm}
\setlength{\pageheightDVDTray}{224mm}
```

I created a command that creates a new geometry for the geometry package:

```
\newcommand{\generatePageLayouts}{%
  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray,layoutheight=\pageheightDVDTray,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray}
}%
```

I created a command that switches to the new layout:

```
\newcommand{\switchToLayoutDVDTray}{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \pdfpageheight=\pageheightDVDTray % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \paperheight=\pageheightDVDTray     % for TikZ
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}
```

I loaded the commands immediately after `\begin{document}`

```
\generatePageLayouts
\switchToLayoutDVDTray
```

## Situation

I have a shared preamble that must have certain dimesions specified like the following:

```
\usepackage[%
     a4paper,
     head=1.5cm,%\baselineskip,  % distance from bottom of header to block of text aka \headsep e.g. \baselineskip
     foot=1.5cm,  % distance from top of footer to block of text aka \footskip
     headheight=12pt,     % height for the header block (no equivalent for footer)
     marginparwidth=2cm,  % right marginal note width
     marginparsep=2mm,    % distance from text block to marginal note box
     top=2.5cm,           % distance of the text block from the top of the page
     bottom=3cm,
     left=2.5cm,
     right=2.5cm,
 ]{geometry}
```

One of my documents needs to use many variables from the preamble, but has a different paper size. Changing the page dimensions for TikZ is proving to be difficult.

## Example Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[%
     a4paper,
     head=1.5cm,%\baselineskip,  % distance from bottom of header to block of text aka \headsep e.g. \baselineskip
     foot=1.5cm,  % distance from top of footer to block of text aka \footskip
     headheight=12pt,     % height for the header block (no equivalent for footer)
     marginparwidth=2cm,  % right marginal note width
     marginparsep=2mm,    % distance from text block to marginal note box
     top=2.5cm,           % distance of the text block from the top of the page
     bottom=3cm,
     left=2.5cm,
     right=2.5cm,
 ]{geometry}
\newlength{\pagewidthDVDTray}
\newlength{\pageheightDVDTray}
\setlength{\pagewidthDVDTray}{130mm}
\setlength{\pageheightDVDTray}{224mm}
\newcommand{\generatePageLayouts}{%
  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray,layoutheight=\pageheightDVDTray,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray}
}%
\newcommand{\switchToLayoutDVDTray}{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \pdfpageheight=\pageheightDVDTray % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \paperheight=\pageheightDVDTray     % for TikZ
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text,positioning}
\begin{document}
\generatePageLayouts
\switchToLayoutDVDTray


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Page Anchors
    \node [yshift=-119.98mm,inner sep=0,shape=circle,fill=red,draw] (origin) at (current page.north) {};
    \node [inner sep=0] (east anchor) at (origin -| current page.north east) {};
    % a random point of the circle



    \begin{scope}[even odd rule, remember picture,overlay]
        \clip
            (origin) circle (14mm) % Inner circle
            (origin) ++(0:60mm) arc (0:360:60mm);
        \node [shape=circle,draw,color=red,minimum width=120mm] (physicalArea) at (origin) {Node Circle}; % Physical Disk Edge
        \node [shape=circle,draw,color=green,minimum width=119mm] (printableArea) at (origin) {};
        \draw [fill=blue!20] ($ (origin) + (0,-5mm) $) rectangle ++(-46mm,-46mm);
        \node [shape=circle,minimum width=28mm,color=red,draw,thick] (innerRing) at (origin) {};
        \def \myradius {59mm}
        %\draw [blue,thick] ($ (origin) + ({\myradius*cos(0)}, {\myradius*sin(0)}) $) arc (0:360:\myradius) ;
        \path[draw,color=orange,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\tiny|text along path test},text align=center,reverse path}}]
        ($ (origin) + ({\myradius*cos(0)}, {\myradius*sin(0)}) $) arc (0:-180:\myradius);
    \end{scope}

    % Layout Scope
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule, every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]
        \tikzset{layout lines/.style={->|,dashed,blue}}
        \draw [layout lines] (origin) -- (current page.north) node [pos=.75,left] {Vertical Offset B: 119.98mm};
        \draw [layout lines] (origin) -- (east anchor) node [pos=.5,above] {Horizontal Offset A: 65mm};


        \node [align=center,anchor=north] at ($ (physicalArea.south) + (0,-5mm) $) {%
            {\Large\bfseries Calibration for Disk Tray J on Printer iP7250}\\
            Ensure that the printer is not automatically scaling the output in the advanced tab of the initial print dialog.\\[5mm]
            {\bfseries Physical Disk Tray Dimensions:}\\
            Height = 224 mm\\
            Width = 130 mm\\
            Margins = 0 mm};
            \clip
                (origin) circle (14mm) % Inner circle
                (origin) ++(0:60mm) arc (0:360:60mm);
            \draw [layout lines] (innerRing.west) -- (printableArea.west) node [pos=.5,above] {Printable Area: 45mm};
            \path [draw,red] (origin) ++(145:60mm) node [inner sep=0] (arbitrary145) {};
            \draw [layout lines,pos=.5,above,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,reverse path,raise=4pt,text align=center,text={|\scriptsize\color{blue}|Physical Area: 46mm}}}] (origin) -- (arbitrary145) ;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: First remark, don't use absolut dimensions like 119.98mm in\node [yshift=-119.98mm,inner sep=0,shape=circle,fill=red,draw] (origin) at (current page.north) {}; try to replace this by some thing \textheight, \paperheight, .8\paperheight

Comment: No, it is absolutely necessary to use absolute dimensions. It is a finely-tuned document to fit a DVD printing tray.

Comment: did you see my last comment below

Comment: Where did your solution go? strange.

Comment: I decided to delete it as you choose to ignore it, but irepeat you can uncomment   %\savegeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} and %\loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} your code will work fine

Comment: an other solution is \newcommand{\switchToLayoutDVDTray}{%
\loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray}
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \pdfpageheight=\pageheightDVDTray % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \paperheight=\pageheightDVDTray     % for TikZ  % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}

Comment: Nonsense. This website does not condone deleting viable answers because they are "ignored" I hope. Allow me to suggest reinstating your answer for the benefit of this site. I would also suggest that we keep the  chatting to a minimum. Comments should be for contributions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is redefine the two commands like this

```
\newcommand{\generatePageLayouts}{%
  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray,layoutheight=\pageheightDVDTray,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm}
  %\savegeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray}
}%
\newcommand{\switchToLayoutDVDTray}{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \pdfpageheight=\pageheightDVDTray % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \paperheight=\pageheightDVDTray     % for TikZ
  %\loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
}
```

moreover you don't need

```
\generatePageLayouts
```

at all

Edit: or you can just redefine

```
\newcommand{\switchToLayoutDVDTray}{%
\loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} %
\pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \pdfpageheight=\pageheightDVDTray % for PDF output
\paperwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray \paperheight=\pageheightDVDTray     % for TikZ
 }
```

Why?
to change pdfpagewidth and height you need newpage. loadgeometry do this but you had call it later

**Edit: more explanation**

when we call

```
\generatePageLayouts
```

we save a newgeometry that's

```
layoutwidth=\pagewidthDVDTray,layoutheight=\pageheightDVDTray,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm
```

but we save implicitly the paper size here a4. Next when we call

```
\switchToLayoutDVDTray
```

we define new pdfpage size

```
\pdfpagewidth \pdfpageheight
```

and paper size 
    \paperwidth \paperheight 
but this paper size will be destroyed by

```
\loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray}
```

which active the geometry saved so the paper size is a4.
Now the pdfpage is correctly=224*130 but the paper size in tikz eyes (as commented in the OP's code) is a4 and the current page.north is in top at 105mm from left and not at 65mm.

Comment: Could you please explain how `current page.center` is exactly 119.98mm below `current page.north`?

Comment: No it is not it is 112mm=224/2 below

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought. That is exactly why I cannot accept your answer. As I said above, this document is finely-tuned for a specific print on a specific tray. The origin must be exactly 119.98mm below `current page.north`.

Comment: you can use \setlength{\pageheightDVDTray}{239.96mm} no?

Comment: can you explain more your need

Comment: your realy problem is not here it is with  \generatePageLayouts \switchToLayoutDVDTray the two do nothing if you don't accept what i proposed in this way you can simply uncomment \savegeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} and \loadgeometry{LayoutPageDVDTray} and your code will be fine

Comment: @macmadness86 i edited my answer